# How to use decorators on a function of a Base Class and have the decorator work on that function when the Base Class is inherited

Tags: python, class, inheritance, python-decorators

I have a base class `Example` with an abstract method `example`. I want to add another decorator on the `example` function, which I have done below - the decorator is `@foo`.

When I use this base `Example` class to create new classes where I create an appropriate `example` function, what `@foo` should do, doesn't end up working.

I believe the issue is that it is being 'overridden' when I create the `example` function on a new class.

```
from abc import ABCMeta, abstractmethod

class Example(object):
    __metaclass__ = ABCMeta

    def __init__(self):
        self.num = 0

    @abstractmethod
    @foo
    def example(self, output):
        pass

class ExampleSum(Example):
    def example(self, output):
        self.num = self.num + output
```

Any guidance? Basically I would like `@foo` behavior to be in the `example` function of `ExampleSum` without explicitly coding it.

Answer (score 1):

> I believe the issue is that it is being 'overridden' when I create the
>   example function on a new class.

You are absolutely right: decorated method gets overriden. But you can archieve your goal if you make abstract only the "inner part" of `example`:

```
from abc import ABCMeta, abstractmethod

class Example(object):
    __metaclass__ = ABCMeta

    def __init__(self):
        self.num = 0

    @foo
    def example(self, output):
        return self._example_impl(output)

    @abstractmethod
    def _example_impl(self, output):
        pass

class ExampleSum(Example):
    def _example_impl(self, output):
        self.num = self.num + output
```